# How to call a TypeScript function from a JavaScript file and have it appear in intellisense?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I started beginning to learn TypeScript. So far I am liking it. Now I have ran into an issue. When I start typing in a JavaScript file, like a function from my TypeScript file, its not showing up in intellisense. Why is this and how can I fix it so when I am working with the contents of a TypeScript file that intellisense catches it?

**EDIT**

[image: Errors]

Link to project

[Project link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmAp9W7a2SLqg0TUwvmp4jWwkF39)

Comment: You're trying to call a TypeScript method from a JavaScript file and have it autocomplete? That's highly dependent on your IDE, I know WebStorm/IntelliJ supports it.

Comment: @PaulBGD, that is correct. I am using Visual Studio 2015.. I wonder if I should reword my question because you hit the nail on the head

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options available to you, it's been a little while since I've tried them out so I would recommend seeing which works for you.

**1. Adding a reference comment to your JavaScript file**

The JavaScript editor built into Visual Studio allows you to extend the JS intellisense by adding references to JavaScript files via the following comment that should be placed at the top of your JavaScript file.

```
/// <reference path="../app/your-transpiled-ts-file.js" />
```

**2. Referencing JS files via Visual Studio's options**

You can also do a similar thing on a global level via Options > JavaScript > IntelliSense > References.

See [this article by Mads Kristensen for more information](http://madskristensen.net/post/improved-javascript-intellisense-in-visual-studio).

**3. TypeScript's `allowJs` option**

One of the new exciting features in TypeScript (1.8 I believe) is the `allowJs` flag that can be set to `true` within your project's `tsconfig.json` file.

Enabling this allows you to use TypeScript definition files within JavaScript and get the full intelliSense experience you'd expect.

Here's a [video of TypeScript's creator, Anders Hejlsberg demonstrating this at the recent Build 2016 event](https://youtu.be/6wEVu_mkJjM?t=2311) that I'd recommend taking a look at (I've linked directly to the part where he starts to talk about the `allowJs` flag).

Comment: #3 looked the most promising and this is what I did and the error that I get
Created MVC Project, 
Updated packages, 
Installed jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped from NuGet, 
Created a New TypeScript file, 
Added the reference jquery.d.ts in the TypeScript file, 
Added TypeScript JSON Configuration file, 
Added "allowJs":true, 

and get errors: Build:Cannot Write file ... because it would override input file

Comment: Does it tell you what file you'd be overwriting? This sounds like an issue with your editor rather than TypeScript. Including TypeScript definition files should be done via NPM as of TypeScript 2.0 so it's possible there could be some conflict?

Comment: I made an edit and added a screenshot of the errors that I am getting when compiling now... I am using the editor in Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Is your source code up on GitHub anywhere? That seems an odd error. Do you have any includes such as `import * as test from "../";`? Could you try run `tsc --traceResolutions` too from your project root please?

Comment: Made another edit and added a link to the project

I don't tsc or NPM, I downloaded TypeScript for VS2015, installed it and did the steps that I mentioned in an earlier comment

Comment: Can you try specifying an output directory please by adding `"outDir": "./dist"` to your tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Ok, did that, no more errors. but none of the Methods are appearing in intellisense

Comment: What version of TypeScript do you have installed? Have you tried restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132742/discussion-between-chris-and-joseph-woodward).